# AttributeError: 'VersionInfo' object has no attribute 'semantic_version'

Tags: python, pip

When use pip version 6.0+ to install a package, I got an error like the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it's mainly because a dependency was installed using an earlier version of pip. To fix it, try `pip install --upgrade pip` followed by using pip to install the package again.